# Targeting every consecutive pair of li elements, possible with CSS3?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-selectors

I want to append some CSS to a series of li elements, but only for every consecutive pair after missing one out. Example of the ones in a series I would want to target:

**1

3/4

6/7

9/10

12/13**

It doesn't look as if `li:nth-child` can help me out since the `n` is an constant integer.

Is there anyway to hijack this and trick the css a little? Adding a `+li` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule to target those `li`s:

```
li:not(:nth-child(3n+2)){
    color:#c00;
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/Vc7qY/)

Comment: Incredible! CSS3 has an answer for everything! Thank you @kei